# ST_Within with wrong results

Tags: within

I have a set of points and a polygon and want to select the points that are within the area. Both layers are in the same projection (WGS84 - EPSG: 4326) and are valid.

To determine which points are within the area i'm using `ST_Within` but the function is returning elements that are not within the area. You can run this query to test it out:

```
with
points as (
 select '0101000020E61000009B8BBFED094A22C0C8CA2F83315C4340'::geometry as geom
 union all
 select '0101000020E61000007C5EF1D4237522C0D0E5CDE15A614340'::geometry as geom), 
area as (
 select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geometry as geom
)
SELECT points.*
, ST_Within(points.geom,area.geom)
, ST_IsValid(points.geom) valid_point
, ST_IsValid(area.geom) valid_area
from points, area;
```

[image: points and area being used]

Only one point is inside the area but I'm getting this results (ST_Within says that both are inside):

```
                         geom                       | st_within | valid_point | valid_area 
----------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+------------
 0101000020E61000009B8BBFED094A22C0C8CA2F83315C4340 | t         | t           | t
 0101000020E61000007C5EF1D4237522C0D0E5CDE15A614340 | t         | t           | t
(2 rows)
```

I'm using:

- PostGIS Version: “POSTGIS="2.4.8 r17696" PGSQL="96" GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.3.2, released 2018/09/21" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11" LIBPROTOBUF="1.0.2" (core procs from "2.4.7 r17330" need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.4.7 r17330" need upgrade)”
- PostgreSQL Version: PostgreSQL 9.6.15 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit
- SO Version: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) [Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64]

Does anyone get the same result?

Comment: if both geometries are in 4326 why are you transforming them?

Comment: I have checked it and it works as expected.

Comment: @Ian Turon, It's just for getting that issue out of the way. I guess that the first questions would be the projections and validity of the features. 
However, the result is the same if I don't transform them.

Comment: Just like @Ayaz49 I get also "false" for the latter point with your query when I just copied and pasted it into PgAdmin. My PostGIS is `"2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"`.

Comment: They are multipoints but just with one member. What is interesting is why the query returns "true" for @georamos but not for others.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

I've simplified the query. Got rid of the transformations and changed MULTIPOINT to POINT and MULTIPOLYGON to POLYGON. 

Unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: @user30184, can you please check what is your full version by running SELECT postgis_full_version(); ?

I've tested it on another server with another version of PostGIS and got a good answer. This server runs  POSTGIS="2.4.5 r16765" PGSQL="96" GEOS="3.6.3-CAPI-1.10.3 80c13047" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.4, released 2016/01/25" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11" (core procs 
from "2.4.4 r16526" need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.4.4 r16526" need upgrade)... Sure thing it won't get any upgrade soon... :)

Comment: It is `"POSTGIS="2.5.1 r17027" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.0-CAPI-1.11.0 3.7.1" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" RASTER"`

Answer (score 1):

This is your initial request + ST_Dump function

```
WITH 
points as (
  SELECT
(ST_Dump((ST_SetSRID('0104000020E61000000100000001010000009B8BBFED094A22C0C8CA2F83315C4340'::geometry, 4326)))).geom as geom
  UNION 
  SELECT (ST_Dump((ST_SetSRID('0104000020E61000000100000001010000007C5EF1D4237522C0D0E5CDE15A614340'::geometry, 4326)))).geom as geom), 
area as (
  SELECT (ST_Dump((ST_Set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geometry, 4326)))).geom as geom) 
  SELECT points.* 
, ST_Within(points.geom,area.geom)
, ST_IsValid(points.geom) valid_point
, ST_IsValid(area.geom) valid_area
FROM points, area
;
```

The result of the request:
[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Just ran your query on my server but I'm still getting the wrong answer ...


                        geom                        | st_within | valid_point | valid_area 
----------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+------------
 0101000020E61000009B8BBFED094A22C0C8CA2F83315C4340 | t         | t           | t
 0101000020E61000007C5EF1D4237522C0D0E5CDE15A614340 | t         | t           | t

(2 rows)

Comment: I don't think I'm gonna get to your server...

Comment: Can't blame you @Cyril :)

Comment: By the way, without ST_Dump, I also get my result, PostGIS version 2.2 and PostGIS version 2.5; maybe you have problems in the assembly ...

Comment: what's the assembly?

Comment: see your question after words I'm using:...